# Where is session.Linq?

Tags: nhibernate

I see many examples of using Linq to NH like this:

```
ISession session = getSession();
    var query = from conference in session.Linq<Conference>()
```

But in my code there is no .Linq on ISession.

is the following Using not enough?

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing the right namespace, but using the wrong method on `ISession` interface. Instead of `ISession.Linq<T>()`, use `ISession.Query<T>()`.

```
ISession session = getSession();
var query = from conference in session.Query<Conference>()
```

`ISession.Linq<T>()` was a part of [Linq 2 NHibernate](http://ayende.com/blog/4083/nhibernate-linq-1-0-released), a separate project that was somewhat temporary solution. It was based on Criteria API. It's now obsolete.

The new NHibernate Linq provider is now a part of main NHibernate assembly (as of NH 3.0). It's based on HQL and has a lot more features.

Comment: Thank you!  I suspected that .Linq had become something else, .Query, or .QueryOver, but it was not clear.